# Sentence/participle in brackets?

Tags: grammar

> Reading about the classical giants one after the other, you begin to
>   feel that their fame came at a high price. Many of them were child
>   prodigies (**Mozart being one of the best-known examples**), who were
>   mercilessly pushed to perform; most were plagued by money troubles and
>   ill health throughout their lives; and few enjoyed satisfactory
>   personal relationships.

---

1) In grammar, what kind of structure this sentence in bold use? Is this is a complement composed by present participle?

2) Can I rewrite the sentence/participle in brackets to "Mozart is one of the best-known examples" ? Is this OK?

Comment: It is a subordinate parenthetical clause. It could have been set off with dashes or even commas, but parentheses are the most likely punctuation to be used there. It could be written as you say, with *is* instead of *being*, in which case it would be an independent parenthetical clause. But the meaning would remain the same.

Comment: Interpolations like this are called 'supplements'. Their crucial property is that they are not dependents to any head word, so they are not modifiers; rather they add additional non-integrated content. You can paraphrase the clause as "Mozart being one example of the best-known examples of child prodigies.